# Adding Kmls with innerboundary

Tags: kml, here-api

I'm unable to show kmls with innerboundarys with the JS here api. The kml works in GoogleMaps and Qgis.

Has anyone succesfully added kmls with innerboundarys to the JS .here api?

kml I have been using to test:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
        <Document id="root_doc">
            <Folder>
    <Placemark>
                <name>Test</name>
                    <ExtendedData>
                    </ExtendedData>
                    <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                            <LinearRing>
                                <coordinates>-0.959,50.876,0.0 -0.959,52.309,0.0 0.822,52.309,0.0 0.822,50.876,0.0 </coordinates>
                            </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                        <innerBoundaryIs>
                                    <LinearRing>
                                        <coordinates>-0.85,50.993,0.0 -0.85,52.244,0.0 0.726,52.244,0.0 0.726,50.993,0.0 </coordinates>
                                    </LinearRing>
                                </innerBoundaryIs>
                    </Polygon>
    </Placemark>

            </Folder>
        </Document>
    </kml>
```

Comment: Hi, the KML looks working well. Would you please provide more detail information? for example your code, JS API version, JS API detail spec  and etc.

Comment: You might want to confirm whether or not the Here API supports the innerBoundaryIs tag in KML. It's a pretty basic tag, so should be supported, but it's the kind of thing that might have been overlooked or not tested well.  In the Here documentation I could not find any list of supported/unsupported KML tags. The best I found was on the "KML Support" page, a line that said, "Many KML objects have counterparts in the HERE Maps API", which seems to indicated that some KML objects may not have counterparts in Here Maps.

Comment: Currently HERE API does not support innerBoundaryIs tag. We will have this investigated internally.

Comment: Sorry I havent replied sooner. I didn't see a reply. I have worked around the issue by adding the innerboundary to the outerboundary, e,g, all coords are connected together and I've removed the line styling.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: Currently HERE API does not support innerBoundaryIs tag.
The reporter has worked around the issue by adding the innerboundary to the outerboundary, e,g, all coords are connected together and removed the line styling.